# Formatting Float64Index in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code to create a df by merging to dfs which in turn are grouped by column "År" (Norwegian for Year) (2011, 2012, 2013 etc.)

```
def create_output_from_subset(analysis_type):
    unique_customers_subset = df.groupby('År')['Kundenavn'].nunique().to_frame()
    analyses_count_subset = df.groupby('År')['Kundenavn'].count().to_frame()
    output_subset = pd.merge(unique_customers_subset, analyses_count_subset, left_index = True, right_index = True)
return output_subset
```

The called function returns the following:

> ```
>         Customers  Analyses
> År                         
> 2011.0         46        59
> 2012.0         80       156
> 2013.0         76       148
> 2014.0         69       108
> 2015.0         39        82
> 2016.0         42        90
> 2017.0         23        36
> ```

The Year index (`År`) is formatted as a `Float64Index` showing 1 decimal. Any ideas how I can show it as an `int` (no decimals)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`index.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.astype.html):

```
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
```

But if some `NaN` values in index is not possible.

Need replace them by some `int` and then convert:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]}, index=[2011,2012,np.nan])
print (df)
         a
 2011.0  1
 2012.0  2
NaN      3

df.index = df.index.fillna(1970).astype(int)
print (df)
      a
2011  1
2012  2
1970  3
```

Or remove rows with NaNs first:

```
df = df[df.index.notnull()]
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
print (df)
      a
2011  1
2012  2
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code :

```
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x : int(x))
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks a lot!